# Read subsite list items through Sharepoint HostedApp

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-365, sharepoint-hosted-app

In SharePoint Hosted-App, I want to read specific list items from all subsites.  I can get into subsites, but when I tried to read specific list items, I couldn't. My code:

```
             context = new SP.ClientContext(appweburl);
             factory = new SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory(appweburl);
             context.set_webRequestExecutorFactory(factory);
             appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(context, hostsuburl);
             this.web = appContextSite.get_web();
             context.load(this.web);
             context.executeQueryAsync(
                 Function.createDelegate(this, successHandler),
                 Function.createDelegate(this, errorHandler));
                 function successHandler() {
                     var list = this.web.get_lists();
                     olist = list.getByTitle('list1');
                     var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
                     camlQuery.set_viewXml("some query goes here");
                     oListCollitems = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
                     context.load(oListCollitems, 'Include(ID,Title,Date)');
                     context.ExecuteQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, successHandler1), Function.createDelegate(this, errorHandler1));
                     function successHandler1() {
                         alert('Inside Successhandler1');
                     }
                     function errorHandler1() {
                         alert('Inside Error Handler1')
                     }
```

I'm supposed to get into `successHandler1()`function and read list items. But I'm not get into either `successhandler1()` or `errorhandler1()`. Do I miss something or I'm in wrong way? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have typo in the last async call as javascript is case sensitive. Try executeQueryAsync instead of ExecuteQueryAsync.

```
context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, successHandler1), Function.createDelegate(this, errorHandler1));
```

Comment: I've tried that too, but not working.. still getting same error.. I think i need to recreate from scratch again. Could you pls mention any example for SharePoint hosted app to perform crud operation on all subsites list?